# CAQuietExec: Access denied when trying to execute copyfiles

Tags: windows-installer, impersonation, custom-action, access-denied, error-code

I have an application with custom action (Execute="deferred" Impersonate="yes") which copy files to common files folder. When I am trying to execute the application getting failure by saying

```
MSI (s) (AC:34) [10:50:56:404]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=CopyMfcRun,ActionType=1025,Source=BinaryData,Target=CAQuietExec,CustomActionData="cmd" /C xcopy /E /H /R /X /Y /I /K  "C:\Application\PortalFiles\msv*.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Tom Sawyer Software\10.0.0")

MSI (s) (AC:B4) [10:50:56:409]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIB9F8.tmp, Entrypoint: CAQuietExec

CAQuietExec:  Access denied

CAQuietExec:  0 File(s) copied

CAQuietExec:  Error 0x80070004: Command line returned an error.

CAQuietExec:  Error 0x80070004: CAQuietExec Failed

CustomAction CopyMfcRun returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)

MSI (s) (AC:34) [10:50:56:545]: Note: 1: 2265 2:  3: -2147287035 

MSI (s) (AC:34) [10:50:56:546]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
```

Please help me with this.Customer unable to install our application.

Comment: Try to use `Impersonate="yes"`

Comment: Our custom action has Impersonate=yes  <CustomAction Id ="CopyMfcSet" Property='CopyMfcRun' Value='"cmd" /C xcopy /E /H /R /X /Y /I /K  "[TSPortalIntfFolder]msv*.dll" "[ProgramFilesFolder]Common Files\Tom Sawyer Software\10.0.0"'/>
                                                                      <CustomAction Id ='CopyMfcRun' BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="yes" Return="check"/>